# Java update on windows xp problem

Tags: java

I have JBOSS IDE 1.5(eclipse 3.x) on my windows xp computer and it works fine for years. 
Today when I tried to open JBOSS IDE 1.5, it give me following error when startup:
JVM terminated. Exit code=2

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32\javaw.exe
-Xmx512m
-jar C:\eclipse\startup.jar
-os win32
-ws win32
-arch x86
-launcher C:\eclipse\eclipse.exe
-name Eclipse
-showsplash 600
-exitdata 1128_70
-vm C:\WINDOWS\system32\javaw.exe
-vmargs
-Xmx512m
-jar C:\eclipse\startup.jar
```

But I did not change anything for last time good working. 
So I check javaw.exe on windows/system32 and found it's updated at 2009-07-30.

Really frustrated. How to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the reply here [forums.sun](http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=372397&start=15) ... try it

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that you have a bad JAVA_HOME environmental variable.

Comment: Setting as below and never changed since they are working fine before: 
Java_Home=C:\java\jdk1.5.0_06;
PATH = C:\java\jdk1.5.0_06\bin;...
CLASSPATH=.;C:\java\jdk1.5.0_06\lib;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.5.0_09\lib\ext\QTJava.zip

Comment: "Worked fine for years." It might be time to reinstall.

Comment: Its not getting the path right because your error says, -vm C:\WINDOWS\system32\javaw.exe it should be getting c:\java\jdk1.5.0_06\bin\javaw.exe

Comment: you can also try setting the correct vm in the eclipse.ini file.  Try adding

-vm C:\Java\jdk1.5.0_06\bin\javaw.exe

to c:\eclipse\eclipse.ini